# P&T Matrix error after upgrade to 2.5.5

Tags: matrix, upgrade

I upgraded an EE site to 2.6.1 yesterday and then Matrix from 2.0.8 to 2.5.5. However when 
I went to Add-ons > Fieldtypes > Matrix, nothing happened. Isn't there supposed to be an upgrade script?

When I try to edit any entries, I get the following error:

```
A Database Error Occurred

Error Number: 1054

Unknown column 'is_draft' in 'where clause'

SELECT row_id, col_id_1, col_id_2, col_id_3 FROM exp_matrix_data WHERE field_id = 1 AND entry_id = 3 AND is_draft = 0 ORDER BY row_order ASC

Filename: third_party/matrix/ft.matrix.php

Line Number: 2912
```

I have tried uploading the Matrix files again and then to upgrade but still doesn't work.

Comment: Hey there,

if you could send an email to support@pixelandtonic.com with CP access, we could fix this one for you - there's an intermittent bug with Matrix updating that will be fixed in the next version, but meanwhile we can fix this for you.

Comment: Was this issue resolved as we are getting the same error?

Comment: Hi there, we have the same issue with an upgrade we are running locally - can you share the fix so we can implement?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](http://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation).

Answer (score 0):

Use Field pack instead. P&T deprecated for newer versions of expressionengine.

it will copy your data into itself. so you don't need to worry about datta lose as well.